# How to make multiple json processing faster using pySpark?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am having a list of *json* files within **Databricks** and what I am trying to do is to read each *json*, extract the values needed and then append that in an empty pandas dataframe. Each *json* file corresponds to one row on the final dataframe. The initial *json* filelist length is **50k**. What I have built so far is the function below which does the job perfectly, but it takes so much time that it makes me subset the *json* filelist in **5k** bins and run each one separately. It takes 30mins each. I am limited to use only a **3-node cluster** in Databricks.

Any chance that you could improve the efficiency of my function? Thanks in advance.

```py
### Create a big dataframe including all json files ###
def jsons_to_pdf(all_paths):
  # Create an empty pandas dataframes (it is defined only with column names)
  pdf = create_initial_pdf(samplefile)

  # Append each row into the above dataframe
  for path in all_paths:  
    # Create a spark dataframe
    sdf = sqlContext.read.json(path)

    # Create a two extracted lists of values
    init_values = sdf.select("id","logTimestamp","otherTimestamp").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
    id_values = sdf.select(sdf["dataPoints"]["value"]).rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()[0] 

    #Append the concatenated list each one as a row into the initial dataframe
    pdf.loc[len(pdf)] = init_values + id_values 

  return pdf
```

One json file looks like the following: [image]

And what I want to achieve is to have dataPoints['id'] as new columns and dataPoints['value'] as their value, so as to end up into this:[image]

Comment: please add some sample data and expected output ... just having the code is difficult to understand what you want to achieve. probably the blocking point is comming from a misuse of spark.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: every "id"  exists for each triplet ("imoNo", timestamp, timestamp) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your example, what you want to perform is a pivot and then transform your data into a pandas dataframe.

The steps are :

- Collect all you jsons into 1 big dataframe,
- pivot your data,
- transform them into a pandas dataframe

Try something like this :

```
from functools import reduce 


def jsons_to_pdf(all_paths):

    # Create a big dataframe from all the jsons
    sdf = reduce(
        lambda a,b : a.union(b),
        [
            sqlContext.read.json(path)
            for path
            in all_paths
        ]
    )

    # select and pivot your data
    pivot_df = sdf.select(
        "imoNo",
        "logTimestamp",
        "payloadTimestamp",
        F.explode("datapoints").alias("datapoint")
    ).groupBy(
        "imoNo",
        "logTimestamp",
        "payloadTimestamp",
    ).pivot(
        "datapoint.id"
    ).sum("datapoint.value")

    # convert to a pandas dataframe
    pdf = pivot_df.toPandas()

    return pdf
```

According to your comment, you can replace the list of files `all_paths` with a generic path  and change the way you create `sdf`:

```
all_paths = 'abc/*/*/*' # 3x*, one for year, one for month, one for day

def jsons_to_pdf(all_paths):

    # Create a big dataframe from all the jsons
    sdf = sqlContext.read.json(path)
```

This will surely increase the performances.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer Steven! When I replace my function with yours I get `ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns` and this is because the **collect** function returns a huge list containing the info of all rows, which cannot be added to the empty pandas dataframe. I can apply a **for-loop** to the list and add each set of values(representing a row) into the empty dataframe, iteratively. But this again might slow down the process. Any thoughts on how to replace the last 3 lines of code to make it do what it was meant to do in the first place? Thanks again!

Comment: i do not really understand why you want to add it line by line. Just create a column and add it to your dataframe. You do not have to create the columns beforehand.Moreover, you have spark dataframes `to_pandas` method that can be used to create pandas dataframe directly.

Comment: @oikonang I totally change the code according to what you provided. But maybe there are still some adjustments to perform.

Comment: Hi @Steven! Your code works as expected! But it still takes a lot of time to perform the processing. To give you an idea, my code runs 100 json files in 1.1 min and your in 1.07. It is better than mine but still if you think that I have 35k json files, it will take 6.4 hours to do the task. Is there a way to take it down somehow? Thank you for your time.

Comment: No, it is not linear ... mine will take less and less time compare to yours

Comment: What is the content of "all_paths" ? can you replace is with some wildcard path ?

Comment: Ah ok! I ran a part of the first 5000 json files to see how long it takes. I will let you know when it ends. The all_paths is a list of strings containing the directories for each .json file. eg. `["abc/2018/01/01/00_10_00.json","abc/2018/01/01/00_20_00.json",... ]`

Comment: @oikonang try to use a generic path with wildcard. I updated my answer in that way. Take a look and let me know if it speeds things up.

Comment: That's insane! The performance increased by 2000%. How come? I really don't get it. So the for loop even within the reduce schema creates such a delay? Thank you very much for the effort @Steven!

Comment: if you want to increase furthermore the performances, add a schema when you read files. do not relly on auto infer schema !